# Lazy loading noSQL data

Tags: firebase, database-design, firebase-realtime-database, database, nosql

How would one construct the nodes if one were to lazy load noSQL data?

Lets say I have a node with **unordered** posts:

```
/posts 
    /$postId
       /timestamp
       /other
```

How would I restructure this such that I can lazy load 5 posts at the time, sorted by timestamp?

**#BONUS**

In Firebase you can use orderByChild(y) and limitToLast(x) to get the last x posts ordered by y. However, if x=5, how could you retrieve posts 5...10?

.

Comment: There is not enough detail to provide you with a specific answer. What is the nature of your data set? How would one expect to load the first 5 posts, next 5 posts, etc. if there is no order implied in the posts? Are you using firebase or some other database management system?

Comment: There are many different approaches to the solution. A simple numbering of posts and storing that in the post:  post_num: 0.... post_num: 9 and then query starting at 5 and ending 9, order by post_num would be a simple solution. Also, in Firebase (data on the server), there is no concept of ordered; while it does it's own 'ordering', there is no guarantee results will be returned in any order. Data should be considered unordered until you order it through structure and calls. It appears you have a timestamp so that works great. I think the bigger question is why do you want to lazy load posts?